# Adding lines dynamically on XML file

Tags: java, xml

I need to add some lines over a new XML file, in a dynamic way.

First test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
cns:Document xmlns:cns="smpcfg.xsd" DatabaseComment="Partial Export">
  <Status NAME="D1" StatusType="D1, Normally closed, Event">
    <Bypass>false</Bypass>
    <ExternalName>BRIGHTON.CB.3940.D1</ExternalName>
  </Status>
  <Status NAME="D2" StatusType="D2, Normally closed, Event">
    <Bypass>false</Bypass>
    <ExternalName>BRIGHTON.CB.3940.D2</ExternalName>
  </Status>
</cns:Document>
```

the lines that I want to add to each `<Status>` element:

```
<Control NAME="Trip">
  <DeviceName>TRIP</DeviceName>
  <Timeout>60</Timeout>
</Control>
<Control NAME="Close">
  <DeviceName>CLOSE</DeviceName>
  <Timeout>60</Timeout>
</Control>
```

and the final XML, with the expected results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
cns:Document xmlns:cns="smpcfg.xsd" DatabaseComment="Partial Export">
  <Status NAME="D1" StatusType="D1, Normally closed, Event">
    <Bypass>false</Bypass>
    <ExternalName>BRIGHTON.CB.3940.D1</ExternalName>
        <Control NAME="Trip">
            <DeviceName>TRIP</DeviceName>
            <Timeout>60</Timeout>
        </Control>
            <Control NAME="Close">
              <DeviceName>CLOSE</DeviceName>
              <Timeout>60</Timeout>
        </Control>
  </Status>
  <Status NAME="D2" StatusType="D2, Normally closed, Event">
    <Bypass>false</Bypass>
    <ExternalName>BRIGHTON.CB.3940.D2</ExternalName>
       <Control NAME="Trip">
          <DeviceName>TRIP</DeviceName>
            <Timeout>60</Timeout>
        </Control>
        <Control NAME="Close">
              <DeviceName>CLOSE</DeviceName>
              <Timeout>60</Timeout>
        </Control>
  </Status>
</cns:Document>
```

That is, I need to add these lines, for each "status".

Could you give an idea? In Java, or any language.

Comment: A regex replace would do: `s = s.replaceAll("</Status>", "...\r\n...\r\n  $0");`

Comment: There are a lot of Java XML APIs (including the inbuilt DOM/SAX parsers), command line tools, and tools in other languages to do this. Regex-based solutions can be error-prone.

Comment: I'd use XSLT, (Java has a native XSLT 1 processor embedded, Saxon is a good alternative for XSLT 2, which is probably not necessary in this simple case).